# heroku app used as staging environment is crashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, staging

I jumped on an already existing project to do some edits, and the owners of the app and I decided it would be best to set up a "staging" instance on heroku (the production version is up there as well), so they can see my edits before pushing to production.

So I went and set up a new heroku instance for the app. I pulled the code from the production environment, linked it to its bitbucket remote, then ran 
`"heroku create --remote staging"`, followed by `"git push staging master".` (btw if there's a better way to create a staging environment, I'm open to it!)

The app pushed, and loads, but when I try to log in, I get a "We're sorry, but something went wrong". So I ran `heroku logs --app appname`, and I get the following :

```
The requested API endpoint was not found. Are you using the right HTTP 
verb (i.e. GET vs. POST), and did you specify your intended version with the Accept header?
```

I looked around, and didn't find anything that really helped. Any help is appreciated, I'm assuming it has something to do with a database being used. I tried running `heroku run rake --app appname db:migrate`, but I get the following error:

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... failed
 !    Resource not found
```

Also, here's my gemfile for reference:

```
#ruby version
ruby '2.1.4'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
#Use Bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
#Autoprefixer adds the proper vendor prefixes to your CSS code when it is compiled.
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
# Add Haml
gem 'haml-rails'
# Support Mongodb
gem 'mongoid'
# Add simple form
#add BSON support
gem 'bson_ext'
#for simple forms
gem 'simple_form'
# Add paranoia so we can recover things that are deleted
gem 'mongoid_paranoia'
#Include 'rails_12factor' gem to enable all platform features
#See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-integration-gems for more information.
gem 'rails_12factor'
#add devise
gem 'devise'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

#add figaro to ensure secure ENV config variables that can't be accidently git commited
gem "figaro"

#generate PDF's using heroku add on
gem 'doc_raptor'

#mailchimp api for adding confirmed signups to mailchimp
gem 'mailchimp-api', require: 'mailchimp'

gem 'kaminari'

#gem factory girl, to use as fixtures for testing
gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"

#warden gem for testing authentication
gem "warden"

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'therubyracer', :platform=>:ruby
end

#Gems used for devlopment and testing environment
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'capybara'
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

Any help is appreciated, I can post more info if required but I don't know where to look right now. Thanks!

Comment: something is missing either in the source or heroku. I assume the source file is identical to production (which runs nicely), so something is missing in  heroku. I'd start with checking that the db is there and properly initialized by `heroku pg:psql -a appname`

Comment: I tried it, I got "resource not found" - that being said, I'm running MongoDB, not postgres. Does that change the command at all?

Comment: are you able to connect to that mongo instance?